# Diferenciar entre terminal móvil y Monitor en grandes resoluciones

Tags: css3, bootstrap-3

Estoy haciendo un diseño de una web usando bootstrap 3 .

Al hacer el diseño para terminales de gran resolución , me encuentro que los teléfonos actuales tienen el mismo ancho que los monitores grandes `.col-lg-`

Al implementar un `input` con 100% en el móvil aparece correctamente, pero no así en PC, ya que éste ocupa todo el ancho de la pantalla.

¿Cómo se puede diferenciar los móviles de los Monitores de más de 1200px?

Comment: Se deben de utilizar distintos css con sus respectivas media queris, y previamente haber difirenciado si es movil de PC con un script tipo 
 Mobile_Detect() ??

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar con esto, cuando el ancho del browser sea igual o mayor a 1200px se va a aplicar el estilo que definas:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Con la regla **`@media` de CSS** puedes hacerlo:

```
@media screen and (orientation: landscape) and (min-width: 1200px) {
    /* Aquí añadirás todos tus nuevos estilos para cuando ocurra la condición de arriba */
    input {
        width: 50%;
    }
}
```

Eso sí, recuerda que sería suficiente con **`(orientation: landscape)`**, pero si quieres que **solamente ocurra cuando el ancho de la pantalla sea superior al alto y el mínimo ancho sea de (en este caso 1200px)** utiliza lo que te he escrito arriba, de todos modos te dejo una guía sobre la regla [**`@media` de CSS**](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Espero que te sirva de ayuda

Answer (score 0):

En este caso es suficiente con una media query normal:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {

 }
```

Si no estás siguiendo la tendencia *mobile first*, en lugar de `min-width` tienes que usar `max-width`.

Por último, para saber si el usuario está usando un dispositivo móvil basta con obtener en *user agent* :

```
if (isMobile()) {
  // hacer algo
}

function isMobile () {
  const agent = navigator userAgent;

  return (
    agent.match(/Android/)
    || agent.match(/iPhone/)
    || agent.match(/iPad/)
    || agent.match(/webOS/)
    || agent.match(/BlackBerry/)
    || agent.match(/Windows Phone/)
  );
}
```

O si prefieres mantener las cosas sencillas, puedes usar una librería como [isMobile](https://github.com/kaimallea/isMobile).